# Как реализовать движение элементов?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите как у себя на сайте реализовать такие анимированные надписи, появление элементов, например как на данном слайдере https://sketchthemes.com/samples/invert-business-demo/?no_redirect=true

При помощи чего делается? 
Можно ли подсмотреть у этого сайта в коде, как это реализовано?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решил эту проблему.
Скачайте архив wow-animation, это можно сделать отсюда http://sergeychunkevich.com/animaciya-elementa-pri-skrollinge-kombinaciya-animate-css-wow-js/
тут же можно и прочесть инструкцию. Оказалось всё просто. Если нужна какая то другая анимация, то можно выбрать по ссылке внутри этой же статьи.

Comment: Рад, что Вы нашли для себя верное решение.

Answer (score 5):

Если приглядеться ко всем объектам (их обёрткам), которые красиво шевелятся, то у них есть атрибуты с очень "подозрительными" названиями, такими как `data-transform_out`, `data-transform_in` и `data-transform_idle`. В них соответственно хранится всё то, что будет происходить с объектом при появлении на экране, при переключении этого слайда и задержка отработки анимации.

Отыграть анимацию можно, производя парсинг данных из этих атрибутов в наиболее удобный для Вас формат и далее передавая их в метод обработки этих данных. Соответственно производить этот процесс надо при нажатии на кнопку переключения на следующий слайд.

Самым хорошим вариантом будет использовать нативные средства CSS, то есть свойство `transition`, оно старается задействовать GPU, так что это скорее всего уйдет в отдельный поток и будет быстрым.

Если не хочется с этим мучиться, существует специальная библиотека для анимации [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap), она неплохо заоптимизирована.

Так же популярный способ создания анимации - это использовать jQuery. В нём есть специальный метод [`jQuery.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), он достаточно прост для понимания. Кстати, на указанном Вами сайте, именно это и делается.

Ну и конечно сейчас медленно, но верно воплощается в жизнь - [web-animation API](http://css-live.ru/articles/pogovorim-ob-web-animations-api.html) и его [полифиллы](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js). Суть у него такая же как и при использовании `transition` в CSS, однако дается гораздо более удобный API.

Comment: Так я хотел услышать как это сделать, а не что с этим можно сделать

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов, а я и написал _КАК_ это сделать, писать всё за Вас можно попросить у фрилансеров за деньги. Если у Вас есть свои собственные попытки это сделать, но не получилось - другое дело, Вы можете добавить их в вопрос.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов на ваш вопрос КАК тогда можно ответить очень кратко – руками